# awk extract data from pattern and write back to the same file

Tags: json, awk, sed

I have a JSON file as the below

```
[
{
    "macAddress": "22:00:10:21:ca:54",
    "GeoCoordinate": {
        "latitude": 1.2345,
        "longitude": 123.4567,
        "unit": "DEGREES"
    }
},
{
    "macAddress": "33:00:11:21:ca:54",
    "GeoCoordinate": {
        "latitude": 2.1345544523,
        "longitude": 123.45678,
        "unit": "DEGREES"
    }
},
{
    "macAddress": "44:00:10:21:ca:14",
    "GeoCoordinate": {
        "latitude": 2.1345544523,
        "longitude": 123.45678,
        "unit": "DEGREES"
    }
}
...
]
```

I want to get the below data so the MongoDB can use Geo index on the lat/long pair with `loc` field.

```
[{
    "macAddress": "22:00:10:21:ca:54",
    "GeoCoordinate": {
        "latitude": 1.2345,
        "longitude": 123.4567,
        "unit": "DEGREES"
    },
    "loc": {
       "lon": 123.4567,
       "lat": 1.2345
     }
},
{
    "macAddress": "33:00:11:21:ca:54",
    "GeoCoordinate": {
        "latitude": 2.1345544523,
        "longitude": 123.45678,
        "unit": "DEGREES"
    },
    "loc": {
       "lon": 123.45678,
       "lat": 2.1345544523
     }
},
{
    "macAddress": "44:00:10:21:ca:14",
    "GeoCoordinate": {
        "latitude": 12345678,
        "longitude": 87654321,
        "unit": "DEGREES"
    },
    "loc": {
       "lon": 87654321,
       "lat": 12345678
     }
}
...
]
```

You can see that I just append the lat/lon values to the json object and reversed the lon/lat order.

How to use `AWK` or other linux command line to process the above file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `jq` command:

```
jq '.[]|=.+{"loc":{"lon":.GeoCoordinate.longitude,"lan":.GeoCoordinate.latitude}}' file
```

Comment: `jq` is easy to use than `awk` for sure, however I would still prefer an `awk` solution just for learning purpose. Thank you.

Comment: Ok first lesson: `awk` is not suited to parse and modify json. Use `jq`.